# Could someone point out what's wrong with my Graph DFS Implementation?

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I think I understand conceptually how a Graph DFS works with a stack but I'm not sure if my implementation is working correctly since the stack seems to be holding multiple identical values.

https://repl.it/@Stylebender/DFS-Graph#index.js

Is there something broken starting from Line 41?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is correct. But u must remove line 26 which is "explored.add(source);" as it prevents the source vertex getting printed.